# Associate thread from DeferredResult and Spring AsyncRestTemplate to Shiro

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, asynchronous, shiro

how can I associate a thread resulting from a Spring deferred result to  Apache Shiro Subject via subject.associateWith(work);

It's clear for callable or runnables but not for the async Spring Objects.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "etc/async/{atbId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> getEtcById(HttpServletResponse response,
                               @PathVariable("atbId") long atbId,                               
                               HttpSession session) throws IOException {

        log.debug("Enter async getEtcById with ListenableFuture");
        final String userName = (String) session.getAttribute(SessionKeys.USER_ID);
        final AuthenticatedAsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AuthenticatedAsyncRestTemplate();

        final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<>(100000); 
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = 
                restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8079/ts.download/download/etc/{atbId}?userName={userName}", String.class, atbId, userName);  

        future.addCallback(  
                  new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {  
                    @Override  
                    public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> response) {  
                        // Will be called in HttpClient thread  
                        log.debug("ListenableFuture onSuccess: " + response.getBody());                         
                        result.setResult(response);  
                    }  

                    @Override  
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {  
                        log.error("ListenableFuture onFailure", t);  
                        result.setErrorResult(t.getMessage());  
                    }  
                });  

        log.debug("Leaving async getEtcById");
        return result;
    }
```

The rest call works but I get this error message:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path
>   [/mycontext] threw exception [java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No
>   SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the
>   org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This
>   is an invalid application configuration.] with root cause
>   org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No
>   SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the
>   org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This
>   is an invalid application configuration.  at
>   org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:123)
>     at org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.(Subject.java:627)
>     at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject(SecurityUtils.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest.getSubject(ShiroHttpServletRequest.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest.getSubjectPrincipal(ShiroHttpServletRequest.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal(ShiroHttpServletRequest.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.getUsernameForRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:996)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:660)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:368)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1636)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:599)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Comment: I think that this can help: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/UnavailableSecurityManagerException-in-MDB-td7578445.html#a7578463